# number of n coin flips with exactly one heads

Tags: probability

There were n Immortal Warriors born into our world, but in the end there can be only one.
The Immortals’ original plan was to stalk the world for centuries, dueling one another with
ancient swords in dramatic landscapes until only one survivor remained. However, after a
thought-provoking discussion of probabilistic independence, they opt to give the following
protocol a try:

1. The Immortals forge a coin that comes up heads with probability p.
2. Each Immortal flips the coin once.
3. If exactly one Immortal flips heads, then he or she is declared The One. Otherwise,
   the protocol is declared a failure, and they all go back to hacking each other up with
   swords

What is the probability that the experiment succeeds as a function of $p$ and $n$?

**my answer:**
we can get heads at the first flip with probability $p$
or the first flip comes up tails and we get heads on the second toss with probability (1 - $p$)* $p$
or on the third with probability (1 - $p$)^2 * $p$
and so on, summing these probabilities gets p * sum((1-p)^i) for i from 0 to $n - 1$ which equals 1 - (1 - p) ^ n

**book answer**:
the sample space is all possible results of n coin flips Let E be the event that the experiment successfully Then E consists of the n outcomes which contain a single head. In
general, the probability of an outcome with h heads and n − h tails is: (p^h)((1-p)^(n - h))
Summing the probabilities of the n outcomes in E gives the probability that the procedure succeeds:
pr{E} = $np$(1-p)^(n-1)

I'm convinced by the book answer, but I don't know what's wrong with my answer

Comment: "*We can get heads at the first flip with probability $p$*" Where do you see it stated that we stop flipping coins after the first flip which is heads has occurred?  If the first person flips heads, shouldn't everyone else still get a chance to flip and isn't it possible that the second person also flips heads which invalidates it, causing them to go back to swordfighting?

Comment: In either event... both answers are poor... they rely on these awkward summations which can be difficult (*especially for beginners*) to simplify.  This is instead much more easily described using the [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) and can be used for a *direct* and *immediate* answer.  Your answer was the correct answer to the wrong problem... it was the answer to the probability of *at least one head* having been flipped, not the probability of *exactly one head* having been flipped.

Comment: I know , totally off-topic , but neverheless : I wonder why such exercises are embedded in fantasy stories with utter lack of fundamental logic and probably exactly because of this so successful. Seems that such Warriors actually stalk our world. This would explain many depressing events in the last years.